# SSR Cache in React?

Tags: reactjs, performance, server-side-rendering

Lately, I'm trying to migrate an old Nodejs project from using `ejs` + `jQuery` to using `React`. This migration will dramatically decrease the cost of the development because the content of the rendered HTML depends on the user information brought by each request, which means before the migration I need to write loads of if/else in ejs templates to decide which part should be rendered. Using react server-side rendering helps me out of this hell.

However, it raises the concern about the performance of rendering the whole application per request without any caching strategy. In my case, I cannot pre-render the HTML page ahead of a user request, so I can't make use of solutions like the [Static Generation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#static-generation-recommended) that Nextjs provided.

I did some searching and found a related [RFC](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/16) post. Though the issue is open, it seems like it remains inactive for a long time and the discussion is stale. Is there already a solution to this problem or it's just something that is out of the scope of React? I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out here.

Comment: The solution of the issue you expect to encounter depends on the exact scenario you are in, ie. what is the relationship between data and templates/component trees generated from it, are you worried about latency or additional CPU resources needed, etc. Also, make some tests if you should worry about it in the first place.

Comment: @catchergeese Thank you for the reply. I'm actually concerned about the time that the render process takes. I want the latency to be as short as possible. And thank you for the advice, I'll do some benchmark testing after the migration is done. It's just seems obvious that rendering from cached template is faster than rendering from scratch.